# Wso2 esb foreach

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB v6.1.1 and facing some issue in foreach/iterator mediator using json as payload. After using the foreach loop it should return all the modified elements but it is observed that only the final element is returned.

The Request I sent is

```
[{  
      "id":101,
      "FirstName":"Kaith",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"kwilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-287-9665",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }

  {  
      "id":102,
      "FirstName":"Rahul",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"Rwilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-333-9665",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }


{  
      "id":103,
      "FirstName":"abishek",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"Awilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-287-4565",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }

]
```

Response Expected

```
[{  
      "id":101,
      "Name":"Kaith",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"kwilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-287-9665",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }

  {  
      "id":102,
      "Name":"Rahul",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"Rwilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-333-9665",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }


{  
      "id":103,
      "Name":"abishek",
      "lastName":"Williams",
      "email":"Awilliams@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"123-287-4565",
      "dateOfBirth":"null"
   }

]
```

Response I got is

```
    [ 
     {  
          "id":103,
          "Name":"abishek",
          "lastName":"Williams",
          "email":"Awilliams@yahoo.com",
          "mobile":"123-287-4565",
          "dateOfBirth":"null"
      }
    ]
```

My Main Xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sam1" name="testsample" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://customers.pcfdev.kpit.com/customers"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <foreach expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement">
                <sequence>

                    <payloadFactory description="" media-type="json">
                        <format>


   [{  
      "id":$1,
      "Name":"$2",
      "lastName":"$3",
      "email":"$4",
      "mobile":"$5",
      "dateOfBirth":"$6"
   }
]
</format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.id"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.firstName"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.lastName"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.email"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.mobile"/>
                            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.dateOfBirth"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="full"/>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

And using log in out-sequence I got proper output in console but not in browser
This same issue is happening with iterator too.

Comment: Hi @Akash,
Did u get any solution for this? i am also getting one payload instead of all.